# While processing a live video stream in python CV2, where are video frames kept in hardisk or RAM?

Tags: opencv, video-processing

On live video (from IP webcam), I am processing in OpenCV and my process lags with the video frames. As I am directly reading webcam in python code, I want to know where frames of video are being kept before they are being processed? Is it using space in Ram or Hardisk or somewhere else? As my process lags from video stream can it let my Pc run continuously for days and months? Oh! I am using OpenCV in Linux on a core i5 laptop with 8 Gb RAM, if that matters.

Comment: > "As my process lags from video stream can it let my Pc run continuously for days and months? Oh! I am using OpenCV in Linux on a core i5 laptop with 8 Gb RAM, if that matters."

Not sure I get what you mean, do you mean that it will flood your RAM until there is no memory left making the program to crash?

Comment: Yea will it flood the RAM  ?

Comment: Somebody else will have to give you a definite answer but from my own experience it will not do that as frames are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it using space in Ram or Hardisk or somewhere else?

It is using the RAM.

Comment: It means If it continuously keeps lagging, it will soon flood the RAM and the program will crash ? Is there way to avoid this problem?

Comment: What if I try to save that continuous live streaming in hardisk through a browser and meanwhile read the video in python program? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, I am working on Image Processing stuff with that video. Lag has nothing to do with memory but frames are being loaded in RAM? Don't you think it can crash the program?

Comment: Might be that your image processing is computationally intensive, what exactly are you doing? My recommendation: Don't worry about the memory management for now, that is not the reason behind the lagging.

Comment: I am doing some feature detection and feature matching on each face i see in video frames. If there is no face then feature detection and matching is skipped for that frame. As i have noticed my task is running on  one or two frame per second. Its too low rate. As IP webcam is continuously running where will the frames be saved if the process lags behind thousands of frames ?